# Any one know how to Apache hive data visualization using D3js?

Tags: d3.js, hive

Any one know how to do [Apache hive](http://hive.apache.org/)  data visualization using [D3js](http://d3js.org/)??

Comment: Twitter Ambrose uses D3.js for diagram generation. It's for Pig, but
I've coded an extension to support Hive. See: https://github.com/lbendig/ambrose/tree/ambrose-hive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Hive Query like

```
SELECT b.blogID, count(b.name) FROM comments a LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.value, 'blogID', 'name') b 
AS blogID, name group by b.blogID;
```

and make as `Json_tuple` then you can easily use That **json** to **D3js**

Answer (score 2):

try it using sqoop..
using sqoop transfer data from hive to mysql or any other RDMS,den using python retreive the data to json file,
finally create d3js from the json file.